# eslint throwing errors where there are no errors

Tags: javascript, eslint

I’m receiving the following errors when running `yarn eslint`:

```sh
/…/src/a.js
  4:1   error  Expected indentation of 1 tab but found 2 spaces   indent
  4:43  error  Strings must use singlequote                       quotes
  5:1   error  Expected indentation of 2 tabs but found 4 spaces  indent
  6:1   error  Expected indentation of 1 tab but found 2 spaces   indent
  6:6   error  Strings must use singlequote                       quotes

✖ 5 problems (5 errors, 0 warnings)
  5 errors and 0 warnings potentially fixable with the `--fix` option.
```

This is my `.eslintrc.js` file:

```js
module.exports = {
    env: {
        browser: true,
        es2021: true,
    },
    extends: [
        'eslint:recommended',
        'plugin:react/recommended',
    ],
    parserOptions: {
        ecmaFeatures: { jsx: true },
        ecmaVersion: 12,
        sourceType: 'module',
    },
    plugins: ['react'],
    settings: {
        react: { version: 'detect' },
    },
    rules: {
        indent: [
            'error',
            'tab'
        ],
        'linebreak-style': [
            'error',
            'unix',
        ],
        quotes: [
            'error',
            'single'
        ],
        semi: [
            'error',
            'always'
        ]
    }
};
```

… and the file in question:

```js
import React from "react";
import { css } from "./a.css";

export function App() {
\treturn (
\t\t<div className={css.App}>
\t\t\tHello.
\t\t</div>
\t);
}
```

Note: I include `\t` here to denote tabs as Stack Overflow replaces actual tabs with 4 spaces.

None of the errors reported by eslint are actual errors in the file. All indents are correct, and I only use single quotes. Hell, there isn’t even a line 43 in that file, as eslint is reporting.

What might be happening here?

Comment: i can see a double quote here `import React from "react";` 

Comment: `4:43` means line 4 and 43 character from start of line.

Answer (score 0):

```
indent: [
        'error',
        'tab'
    ],
quotes: [
        'error',
        'single'
    ],
```

This rule in you eslint tell that you shall not use **space** but a **tab Key** for indentation either remove this rule OR on the lines where the INDENT error has occured you shall find space used for indentation remove them and use the Tab key
Also for the **Quote** Error check you variable for the string values saved using single quote, if you are using vscode then you might need to remove this rule or update the vscode setting and prevent it from updating the single quote to double quote while auto saving

Comment: I included the contents of the file being linted and, as you can see, it does’t contain any spaces. Stack Overflow replaced my actual tabs with spaces, so I changed them to `\t` in the code sample. There are no spaces in the indents there.

Comment: These kind of issues usually happens when the code editor setting are in conflict with the eslint setting and maybe you can see who is overriding who the will point you in the right direction

Comment: The code editor doesn’t come into play here. I’m running eslint in the console. This happens even when I disable eslint in Atom.

Answer (score 0):

facepalm.

This ended up being a problem with an aspect of the project I didn’t mention. I’m using [Rollup](https://rollupjs.org/) to bundle by code, along with the `@rollup/plugin-eslint` plugin to run eslint when building. I had my plugins in this order:

```js
plugins: [
    babel({
        babelHelpers: 'bundled',
        exclude: 'node_modules/**',
    }),
    resolve({
        browser: true,
    }),
    eslint({
        include: '**/*.js',
        throwOnError: true,
    }),
    styles({
        modules: true,
    }),
]
```

I just had to move the `eslint()` plugin to the front of the array and all was golden.

```js
plugins: [
    eslint({
        include: '**/*.js',
        throwOnError: true,
    }),
    babel({
        babelHelpers: 'bundled',
        exclude: 'node_modules/**',
    }),
    resolve({
        browser: true,
    }),
    styles({
        modules: true,
    }),
]
```